# Eclipse ignoring the git hooks

Tags: eclipse, gitlab, bitbucket, jgit

Is there a way to make the eclipse read the hooks created from .git/hooks directory? I tried to use the hooks on cli/shell level and it’s working as expected but on eclipse ide,it completely ignores the hooks.

Comment: On which OS? What kind of hook? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello, im using linux when I'm building the hooks (pre-commit and commit-message). But on our prod, we are using ECLIPSE on WINDOWS OS for our GIT.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh
echo "You are commiting"
exit 1`  this is on my pre-commit just to test wether the hooks is working or not.

Comment: Please improve your question instead of commenting your own question. [On Windows, Cygwin is needed to run a hook bash script](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1067404&goto=1698542&#msg_1698542).